# Execute swift when safari extension is opened

Tags: swift, macos, safari, safari-extension

I'm trying to create a Safari App Extension that executes some local Swift code when the Safari popup is opened, instead of executing a classic `script.js` file.

First of all, can I do it? If so, how?

For the permissions, I need to access `activeTab` and `cookies`.

Answer (score 2):

> when the Safari popup is opened

I assume you mean the popover that Safari displays when the `SFSafariToolbarItem` is clicked? Running native Swift code at this point is not a problem if you keep a few things in mind.

1. Create a default macOS app via Xcode:
   [image: step1]
   [image: step2]
2. Add a new "Safari Extension" target to your app:
   [image: step3]
   [image: step4]
3. Make sure that you have selected the correct type of Safari Extension. Because you want to run native Swift code, use the "Safari App Extension" type. "Safari Web Extension" is not suitable for your case. Take a look at the following statement from Apple about this ([Source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions)):

> A Safari web extension adds custom functionality to Safari using
> JavaScript APIs and common file formats from extensions for Google
> Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, and Microsoft Edge browsers. While Safari App
> Extensions are useful for sharing code between your native macOS app
> and Safari, you build Safari web extensions primarily on JavaScript,
> HTML, and CSS, and can repackage them to work in other browsers.

4. By default, the action of the `SFSafariToolbarItem` is `Command`. That's why the `toolbarItemClicked(in:)` method is executed on every click.  However, you want to display the popover, so change the action to `Popover` in the Info.plist file.

```
<key>SFSafariToolbarItem</key>
<dict>
    <key>Action</key>
    <string>Popover</string>
    <key>Identifier</key>
    <string>Button</string>
    <key>Image</key>
    <string>ToolbarItemIcon.pdf</string>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>Run Swift code</string>
</dict>
```

5. Remove all methods except `popoverViewController()` from your `SFSafariExtensionHandler`. `popoverViewController()` is responsible to provide the `SFSafariExtensionViewController` for the popover. So make sure you have implemented this class. `SFSafariExtensionHandler` should now look like this:

```
class SafariExtensionHandler: SFSafariExtensionHandler {
    
    override func popoverViewController() -> SFSafariExtensionViewController {
        return SafariExtensionViewController.shared
    }

}
```

6. Implement the `popoverWillShow(_:)` method in the `SFSafariExtensionHandler` to be able to respond to clicks on the `SFSafariToolbarItem`:

```
override func popoverWillShow(in window: SFSafariWindow) {
    NSLog("Swift code executed")
        
    // TODO: Add your code here
}
```

At this point, the entire implementation is complete. Every time the `SFSafariToolbarItem` is clicked, the `popoverWillShow(_:)` method is called and your native Swift code is executed. Finally, your `SFSafariExtensionViewController` (the popover) is retrieved and displayed via the `popoverViewController()` method.

In summary: you can realize your project, Safari App Extension API provides all functionalities for it. If you still don't understand the implementation after my explanation, here is the corresponding GitHub repository: [StackOverflow72584958](https://github.com/Suboptimierer/StackOverflow72584958). Good luck with your project!